# Rvalues, Lvalues and references confusion

Tags: c++

I've been trying to understand rvalues, lvalues and references and  their usage as a returning values of functions (methods) so i created few small examples for practice purpose.

So firstly, i came up with this code (after reading somewhere, possibly here, that whenever i have a "regular" (without reference) return value for some method, it is considered to be rvalue, exception is when i add reference operator sign in the return value, like in this example:

```
#include <iostream>

int x = 5;
int& References()
{

    return x;
}

int main()
{ 
    References() = 3;

    std::cout << x;

    getchar();
    getchar();
}
```

So here, function References returns lvalue when called, and this code works out just fine, however, since this works, i thought that i can do something similar other way around, and this is what i tried:

```
#include <iostream>

int x = 5;
int References()
{

    return x;
}

int main()
{ 
    int a = References();

    std::cout << a;

    getchar();
    getchar();
}
```

This code works just fine, the output is 5, which means that i successfully assigned value to the variable a, which is something i expected since this function returns "ordinary" integer so it a rvalue.

HOWEVER, 
when i once again add reference operator sign to the return value of function References, again, it works fine:

```
#include <iostream>

int x = 5;
int& References()
{

    return x;
}

int main()
{ 
    int a = References();

    std::cout << a;

    getchar();
    getchar();
}
```

So, even though my function now returns `int&` which is returned as lvalue, this code still works and the output is still 5, which means that i managed to assign the value to my variable a successfully. What is going on here? Any help appreciated!

Comment: How does this relate to Object Oriented Programming?

Comment: `int a = x;` simply initializes `a` by copying `x`'s value. This is the same as `int a = References();`. I'm not sure where the confusion lies. Can you explain what you expected to happen?

Comment: So is the question why can you initialize a non reference with a reference?  I'm not sure why you are surprised by the third code block, it just like the second one does.

Comment: @vandench my mistake, this is not opp, sorry

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux well, my function in second code returns  lvalue, my variable is also lvalue, so i assigned lvalue to lvalue, however, in the case above, function returns rvalue, so in that case, i assigned rvalue to lvalue, and both of these work fine, but if we look at my first code, when i remove reference sign in my function it wont work, it says that left operand must be lvalue, so if it doesn't matter if a return by reference in second and third case, why it matters in the first case?

Comment: @cdummie In the first case you are initializing a reference.  You can't initialize a non const reference to an rvalue.

Answer (score 2):

When you use a reference in an expression or an assignment, it evaluates out to what the reference refers to, not the memory address, which I suppose is what you expect to see.

Compare the output of the following functions:

```
int x = 5;
int& Reference()
{
    return x;
}

int *Pointer()
{
    return &x;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << Reference() << std::endl;
    std::cout << Pointer() << std::endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Ok, so the second expression is basically an address where x is stored

Comment: @cdummie Maybe interesting for you as well: `std::cout << &References()`

Answer (score 2):

When you return by reference you have an `lvalue`, when you return by value you have a `prvalue`. In your case the difference you can read from both of them, but cannot assign to `prvalue`, not clear where is your confusion coming from:

```
int i1 = lvalue; // fine
int i2 = prvalue; // fine
```

but:

```
lvalue = 123; // fine
prvalue = 123; // error
```

closer to your case:

```
int &func1();
int func2();

int i1 = func1(); // fine
int i2 = func2(); // fine

func1() = 123; // fine
func2() = 123; // error
```

more info: [Value Category](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)

Answer (score 1):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/f90831hc(v=vs.140) :

`You can think of an lvalue as an object that has a name. All variables, including nonmodifiable (const) variables, are lvalues. An rvalue is a temporary value that does not persist beyond the expression that uses it.`

The third example is exactly the same as the second one, it's copying the value. You can copy a value from an lvalue just how you can copy a value from an rvalue. If your a variable was of type int& instead, you wouldn't be copying the actual value, you'd just get the same reference. This might help you understand:

```
#include <iostream>

int x = 5;
int& References()
{

    return x;
}

int main()
{ 
    int a = References();
    int& b = References();

    std::cout << a; // 5
    std::cout << b; // 5
    std::cout << x; // 5

    a = 6;
    b = 7;

    std::cout << a; // 6
    std::cout << b; // 7
    std::cout << b; // 7


    getchar();
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Actually bringing MS to this conversation is quite wrong due to their pesky extension allowing implicit rvalue to lvalue conversion.

Comment: Microsoft's C++ documentation is often confusing (and sometimes wrong). For instance, `*new int = 3;` involves an lvalue that doesn't have a name.

Answer (score 1):

For comparison:

```
int  n = 10;
int& r = n;
int* p = &n;

int x = n;  // copy by value
int y = r;  // copy by value, too, use the variable referenced as source
int z = *p; // copy by value third time, using variable pointed to

int& r0 = r; // copy the reference, i. e. r0 now references n as well
int* p0 = p; // copy the pointer...

n = 12;
// now x, y, z all STILL have value 10!
// r, r0, *p and *p0, in contrast, all yield 12
```

Not different with functions:

```
int& ref() { return n; }
int val() { return n; }

int& r1 = ref(); // copy the reference, again r1 references n!
int& r2 = val(); // INVALID!!!
// the latter is comparable to:
int& r3 = 7;     // invalid...
```